# How Do I execute a .sh script using cpanel cron job

Tags: cron, cpanel

Im very new to command line so please forgive my ignorance. I can succesfully execute my script using putty by navigating to the relevant direcotry and typing

```
bash app_auth.sh
```

I'm now trying to set this scipt to run using cPanel cron job. I have tried the following but it doesnt work:

```
*   *   *   *   *   /public_html/app/cron_jobs/app_auth.sh
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 5):

Though this thread is old but I found it unanswered hence replying.

Make sure that you have assigned execute permissions to your app_auth.sh  file. Also, try setting the following cron:

```
* * * * * /public_html/app/cron_jobs/app_auth.sh > /home/YOUR_USER/cron.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for the record, I came across the same problem.

I found [this webpage,](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/what-do-i-put-for-the-cron-job-command) which led me to do this:

`/bin/sh /public_html/app/cron_jobs/app_auth.sh`

And it worked fine!